# server name of MAPI account

Tags: c++, exchange-server, mapi

how can I find out the server name of a MAPI account for Microsoft Exchange Server? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Under Outlook 2010, read the `PR_EMSMDB_SECTION_UID` property. If the property is missing or if using an older version of Outlook, assume `pbGlobalProfileSectionGuid`.
2. Use the GUID from (1) to call `IMAPISession.OpenProfileSection()`.
3. Read `PR_PROFILE_HOME_SERVER` property from the `IProfSect` object returned from (2)

You can play with this in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click IMsgStore and IMAPISession.